# CAAnimation animationDidStop not called with NSAnimationContext

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, delegates, caanimation

I'm animating an NSScrollView scrolling, with this piece of code:

```
    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    NSClipView* clipView = [self contentView];
    NSPoint newOrigin = [clipView bounds].origin;
    newOrigin.x = page*kGalleryWidth;
    [[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:newOrigin];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Now I'm trying to get the event that triggers the end of the animation.
I've read that with a some lines of code, using CAAnimation, I would easily achieve it, but I can't.

I've tried these following code:

```
CAAnimation *moveAnimation = [[self.contentView animationForKey:@"frameOrigin"] copy];
moveAnimation.delegate = self;
[self.contentView setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:moveAnimation forKey:@"frameOrigin"]];
```

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{

  NSLog(@"STOP!");

}

Does someone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:<#(void (^)(void))completionHandler#>]

 [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"animation stop!");
    }];
    NSClipView* clipView = [self contentView];
    NSPoint newOrigin = [clipView bounds].origin;
    newOrigin.x = page*kGalleryWidth;
    [[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:newOrigin];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
dragOperation.draggable.center =dragOperation.initialPoint;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
UIView commitAnimations];




-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"goback"];
}
```